# forms in multiple categories schema

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have an existing table with a list of forms in it that looks something like this:

| ID | FormName | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someform | a |
| 2 | otherform | b |
| 3 | yetotherform | c |
| 4 | etc | ... |

(The form table has many more columns, omitted here.)

I would like to make it possible to have some forms be in multiple categories. I have already made a PHP-driven menu using a simple distinct query that generates a menu from the above table based on the category.

`SELECT DISTINCT category FROM tablename WHERE enabled = '1'`

My first gut reaction was to make the category column into a CSV list of categories like so:

| ID | FormName | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someform | a,b,c |
| 2 | otherform | b |
| 3 | yetotherform | c |
| 4 | etc | ... |

But then I thought that this would break my menu because the distinct query would no longer work, and it also seems like trying to break up the CVS into something I could then compare against with a WHERE clause when later displaying a list of forms in a category somehow would be very inefficient.

I'm guessing I need some kind of second database table or some other column adding? I'm not sure what that would look like. I tried to do some searching, but I probably don't know the terminology for what I am asking.

The solution needs to:

- Be as unobtrusive of the current schema as reasonably possible.
- Be able to have forms in multiple categories, or only in one.
- Work in Mariadb
- Ideally not break my existing menu query/PHP work.

Thank you.

Comment: [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) Use another table to store the relation between a form and its categories : `idForm, idCategory`. This is very common

Comment: Worth a 5 minute read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: `I'm guessing I need some kind of second database table`...yep.